# How to require entire dir for Webpack or Browserify

Tags: requirejs, browserify, webpack

I'm learning how to use Webpack and Browserify so I'm still new at this. It seems to me that there should be an easy way to require entire dirs similar to ./dir/**/*.js but that doesn't seem possible. So if I understand correctly, I only have the following options:

- Put all my require() statements in my entry file (app.js).
- Create an index.js file in each of the directories that I want to require and
  add require statements in that file.
- Use the require-dir package (having npm problems with this one).

Am I missing something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load all files in a subdirectories using webpack without require statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29421409/how-to-load-all-files-in-a-subdirectories-using-webpack-without-require-statemen)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`require.context`](http://webpack.github.io/docs/context.html#require-context).

The following code creates a context with any files matching `.js$` regular expression within `./dir` directory recursively:

```
var req = require.context('./dir', true, /\.js$/);
```

All files within a context are bundled in webpack output.
For example, the file `./dir/foo/bar.js` can be loaded like this:

```
var bar = req('./foo/bar.js');
```

You can also retrieve a list of files in a context:

```
req.keys();
```