# How do I write a Webpack plugin to generate index.js files on demand?

Tags: plugins, code-generation, webpack

In general, I want to know how to do code-generation/fabrication in a Webpack plugin on demand. I want to generate contents for files that do not exist when they are "required."

Specifically, I want a plugin that, when I require a directory, automatically requires all files in that directory (recursively).

For example, suppose we have the directory structure:

- foo

  - bar.js
  - baz.js
- main.js

And main.js has:

```
var foo = require("./foo");
// ...
```

I want webpack to automatically generate foo/index.js:

```
module.exports = {
  bar: require("./bar"),
  baz: require("./baz")
};
```

I've read most of the webpack docs. [github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/How-to-write-a-plugin](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/How-to-write-a-plugin) has an example of generating assets. However, I can't find an example of how to generate an asset *on demand*. It seems this should be a Resolver, but resolvers seem to only output file paths, not file contents.

Comment: https://webpack.github.io/docs/context.html

Answer (score 1):

Actually for your use case:

> Specifically, I want a plugin that, when I require a directory, automatically requires all files in that directory (recursively).

you don't need a plugin. See [How to load all files in a subdirectories using webpack without require statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29421409/how-to-load-all-files-in-a-subdirectories-using-webpack-without-require-statemen)

Doing code-generation/fabrication *on demand* can be done in JavaScript quite easily, why would you *restrict* your code generation specifically to only applied, when *"required"* by WebPack?

As NodeJS itself will look for an index.js, if you *require* a *directory*, you can quite easily *generate* arbitrary exports:

```
//index.js generating dynamic exports
var time = new Date();

var dynamicExport = {
  staticFn : function() {
    console.log('Time is:', time);
  }
}

//dynamically create a function as a property in dynamicExport
//here you could add some file processing logic that is requiring stuff on demand and export it accordingly
dynamicExport['dyn' + time.getDay()] = function() {
  console.log('Take this Java!');
}

module.exports = dynamicExport;
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of webpack's `require.context`. Thanks! However, that doesn't solve my problem. I have literally hundreds, probably thousands of code-points where I require a directory and I need to run custom code to scan the files in that directory and decide what to actually load - essentially an index.js file generated on demand. Right now I have a tool which generates these index.js files and writes them to disk. However, this leaves my file-tree littered with machine-generated index.js files. It would be

Comment: @ShaneBrinkman-Davis Well, then either _monkey-patch_ `require()` or replace the calls to `require` with your own `dynamicGeneratingRequire()` where you need this special behavior if you are using pure NodeJs. For Webpack you would write a custom [Resolver](https://webpack.js.org/api/resolvers/)