# Webpack require dynamic image in a React component

Tags: image, reactjs, webpack

I am using React with Webpack.

I have a React Component that takes a prop which is a url and displays the image.

Since React won't know the image url until runtime, can webpack still 'require' the image url?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

export default class Episode extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
    }

    render(){

        let imageStyle = {backgroundImage: 'url(' + this.props.episode.url +')'}

    return (
            <div className="episode">
                    <div className="image" style={imageStyle}>
                        <h2>{this.props.episode.category}</h2>
                    </div>
                <h3>Episode {this.props.episode.number}</h3>
            </div>
        )

    }
}
```

For reference, my images are located in:

`src/assets/images`

and my webpack is building to `dist`

Comment: Is that url base64 data I take it? If so the important part of this is where you are loading in that data, and what webpack loader you're using for it

Comment: @DominicTobias it is not base 64 data. I get the data by polling my server to figure out the image url related to the specific episode the user is currently viewing

Comment: This might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29421409/how-to-load-all-files-in-a-subdirectories-using-webpack-without-require-statemen

Answer (score 1):

For reference, Jumoels answer was almost there but you can't do an import statement inside a componentWillMount.

My Solution to this was as follows:

```html
class YourComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        
        this.state = {
            image: ""
        };
    }

    componentWillMount(){
        this.state.image = require('../../public/assets/img/' + this.props.img);
    }

    render() {
        return(
           <img src={this.state.image}/>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`import()`](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting-import/#dynamic-import) to load the images dynamically. Then, you can do something like the following in `componentDidMount`:

```
import('path/to/images/' + this.props.episode.url).then(function(image) {
    this.setState({ image: image });
}).catch(function(err) {
    // Do something
});
```

In your `render`-function you can then render a placeholder image, for instance [a transparent gif](http://proger.i-forge.net/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80/[20121112]%20The%20smallest%20transparent%20pixel.html), until `this.state.image` contains something valid.

```
render() {
    const imageSource = this.state.image
        ? this.state.image
        : "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACw=";

    return <img src={imageSource} />;
}
```