# gulp-angular-filesort equivalent in webpack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack

I have exactly the same scenario described in this question: [How to load all files in a subdirectories using webpack without require statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29421409/how-to-load-all-files-in-a-subdirectories-using-webpack-without-require-statemen)

I'm upgrading a large project written in angular 1, which is basically a bunch of JS files across many directories, sorted by [gulp-angular-filesort](https://github.com/klei/gulp-angular-filesort).

In order to force modules to load, I must do something like this in

```
common : glob.sync(['./commonApp.js', './modules/importantModule1App.js', './otherFilesDependingonModules/**/*.js']),
```

Which is obviously a bad approach. Otherwise I get a lot of $injector errors:

```
 [$injector:nomod] Module 'common.importantModule1'
```

What is the approach/alternative to the old filesort way, simply to keep the app working while slowly upgrading it?

Comment: So, how did you migrated to webpack?

Comment: I just did it the hard way, with glob.sync

Comment: Did you find a solution?