# How can I automatically load all JSON files from a given directory in Webpack?

Tags: javascript, json, webpack

Edit: There is [an existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29421409/how-to-load-all-files-in-a-subdirectories-using-webpack-without-require-statemen) about loading multiple files but does not adequately address how to combine JSON files into a single object. See answer below. This question is not a duplicate.

---

I have a directory with 100 or so JSON files that I want to load into my js app, which is bundled via WebPack.

I could go through the initial pain of writing out the following:

```
let data = [
    require('json!./Mocks/0.json'),
    require('json!./Mocks/1.json'),
    // 2 - 98...
    require('json!./Mocks/99.json'),
    require('json!./Mocks/error.json'),
    require('json!./Mocks/foo.json'),
];
```

But I would much rather grab everything automatically so that I don't have to update my code when I add/remove JSON files to that directory in the future. How can I do this?

Comment: Eh... it's *possible*. I think that question might solve my issue, but the example isn't specific to JSON files.  (Except for a footnote in the comments) If that's not enough of a distinction, go ahead and lock this. Otherwise I'll post an answer to this question when I get a chance to come back to this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29421409/how-to-load-all-files-in-a-subdirectories-using-webpack-without-require-statemen) details how to load multiple dependencies, but I had to add some extra code to combine my JSON files into a single object. This is the working solution:

```
// Get filename only.
// Example: './foo.json' becomes 'foo'
function getFileNameOnly(filePath) {
  return filePath.split('/').pop().split('.').shift();
}

// ALL THE JSON!
function loadJson() {
  const requireContext = require.context('json!./Mocks', false, /\.json$/);
  const json = {};
  requireContext.keys().forEach((key) => {
    const obj = requireContext(key);
    const simpleKey = getFileNameOnly(key);
    json[simpleKey] = obj;
  });
  return json;
}
```

Usage example:

```
// ./Mocks/99.json
{
    "name": "ninety nine"
}


// ./Mocks/foo.json
{
    "name": "bar"
}

// App.js
let myJson = loadJson();
console.log(myJson['99']);  // > "Object{name:'ninety nine'}"
console.log(myJson['foo']); // > "Object{name:'bar'}"
```