# Webpack use node 'fs' module during buildtime so browser gets the result of function

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-2

**Question**: is there a way to tell webpack to tell built-in modules modules like *fs*  to execute during build so the browser gets the result of this function, not the function call itself?

**My Situation**:

Currently I'm developing an application for the browser using webpack. I'm trying to use the node 'fs' module in one my files to require the `index.js` files from other directories. For example:

```
plugins
├──plugin1
│   ├── index.js (simply exports an object)
│
├──plugin2
│  ├── index.js (simply exports an object)
|
├──plugin3
│  ├── index.js (simply exports an object)
|
|──index.js (want to require all index.js from each plugin directory here)
```

I'm getting an error with webpack saying: `Can't resolve 'fs' in somepath/node_modules/require-dir`

My file `index.js` located at `plugins/index.js' which is simply trying to require my other files.

```
  //module from NPM which uses the 'fs' module ('im not explicity using it)
  const requireDir = require('require-dir');
  const allPlugins = requireDir('./plugins/'); 
  console.log(allPlugins);
```

Can't resolve 'fs' in '/some_path/node_modules/require-dir'

Comment: Can you post the source where you are importing `fs`?

Answer (score 2):

You have two options here.

1. I haven't used this personally, but you can use `node` config value as specified [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/).

`node: {
  fs: {true, "mock", "empty", false}
}`

Set `fs` to any of the above values.

1. Don't use the `fs` module. It is a built/native modules which may or may not rely on native V8/C++ functions/libraries. Remember that webpack typically bundles assets for the *browser*. So instead of relying on a plugin, you can manually import your plugins like:

`plugins/index.js`

```
const plugin1 = require('./plugin1')
const plugin2 = require('./plugin2')

module.exports = {
  plugin1,
  plugin2
}
```

You could also use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29421409/how-to-load-all-files-in-a-subdirectories-using-webpack-without-require-statemen) answer to polyfill the `require-dir` module.

Comment: Thanks for dropping the link to polyfill `require-dir` I found my solution there =). The requiring of each file also works too, totally forgot about that.

Comment: Starting with webpack 5, the first option is changed, now the ``resolve.fallback`` prop is used to polyfill node libraries. https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvefallback

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Francisco Mateo's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2382650/francisco-mateo) additional link about polyfilling `require-dir`, I learned about the [`context` method](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#require-context) that webpack adds to `require`.

This allows me to do dynamic requires like so in my plugins/index.js file:

```
  //require all index.js files inside of /plugins directory        
  let context = require.context('.', true, /\index\.js/);
  const loadPlugins = function(ctx){
    let keys = context.keys();
    let values = keys.map(context);
    return values;
  }
   //array of values from each index.js require
  console.log('loadPlugins', loadPlugins());
```