# Webpack import array of dynamic modules (known in compile time)

Tags: javascript, webpack

In my project, I want to import specific modules that their actual path is known only during compile.

Let's say that I have **components/A.js**, **components/B.js** and **components/C.js** and in my **App.js** I want to include a subset of them that will be known only in webpack's compile-time (ex. from a JSON)

**What I 've tried - 1**

```js
//App.js
compileData = await getCompileDataSomehow()

import("./components/" + compileData.component + ".js")
   .then( /* Do stuff with component */);
```

This work's nice, but webpack will go and create a chunk for every `components/*.js` file. Also, there will be extra network roundtrips. I feel this is a bit overkill since I will know what component I want when webpack will run. So I tried to *Provide* the array of components without luck because `require([...])` is also considered dynamic.

**What I 've ended up with**

```js
//App.js
import("./components/ALL.js") //this file doesn't actually exists
```

```js
//webpack.config.js

const fs = require('fs')

const componentsToInclude = ["A", "B"] //this will be read from a json


fs.writeFileSync('./src/components/ALL.js',
  `
export default [
    ${componentsToInclude.map(comp => `require("./${comp}.js")` )}
].map(c => c.default);

`)

module.exports = { // config //}
```

This works! But as you can see, this is not an elegant solution, and bugs can easily happen. So does anyone know a proper way to deal with this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this answer I'll assume that, similar to the question, there's a main `App.js` file, and a directory called `components` containing files `A.js`, `B.js`, `C.js`, `D.js`, etc. Only `A.js`, `B.js` need to be bundled, and all other files should be excluded from the bundle, but this is only known at compile time.

## require.context

Webpack provides a way to specify a group of dependencies with the custom, Webpack-specific [require.context](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#requirecontext) method. `require.context` takes four arguments: a path to a directory with the files to include, a boolean to determine whether subdirectories are included, a regular expression to filter files, and a directive for the loading mode.

To bundle all files in the components directory we'd run

```js
// App.js
const req = require.context('./components')
```

*(This is beyond the scope of the original question, but you'd then use `req` to run any exported functions from those files. For example, if each `.js` file had a `default` function exported, to run each `default` function you'd do:*

```js
const req = require.context('./components')
req.keys().forEach( key => {
    req( key )?.default()
} )
```

*For more information in requiring with `require.context` see [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29421409/1427563))*

Since we want to load only `A.js` and `B.js` we must send a regular expression to `require.context` to filter the files. Let's suppose that we knew we'd only need `A.js` and `B.js` when writing `App.js`. We could filter the files with a hardcoded regular expression like so:

```js
// App.js
const req = require.context('./components', true, /(A|B)\.js$/)
```

`/(A|B)\.js$/` is a simple regular expression that returns true if the input is `A.js` or `B.js`. It could easily be extended to allow more files: `/(A|B|C|D)\.js$/`, or to only search specific subdirectories. Webpack will evaluate the regular expression at compile time and only include matching files in the bundle.

However, the problem remains: how do we determine what the filter is when we only know the filenames at compile time?

## webpack.DefinePlugin

Using [webpack.DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) we can define global variables in our `webpack.config.js` that are defined at compile time, and that Webpack makes statically available to every file. For example, we could put our regex from before into a global variable called `__IMPORT_REGEX__`:

```js
//webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
    ...
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin( {
            __IMPORT_REGEX__: "/(A|B)\\.js$/"
        } )
    ]
}
```

```js
// App.js
const req = require.context('./components', true, __IMPORT_REGEX__)
```

Note that the value of variables created via `DefinePlugin` must be stringified; that is, we can't supply a raw RegExp value. This means that any backslashes must be escaped.

If we have the names of our files in an array, perhaps previously read from a JSON file, we can dynamically build the needed regular expression in our `webpack.config.js`. In this example it's a simple case of `join`ing the array with the `|` character as a separator:

```js
// webpack.config.js
const fileNames = ["A", "B"];

const importRegex = `/(${ fileNames.join("|") })\\.js$/`; // will return '/(A|B)\\.js$/'

module.exports = { ...
```

## Putting it all together

```js
// webpack.config.js
const fileNames = ["A", "B"];

const importRegex = `/(${ fileNames.join("|") })\\.js$/`;

module.exports = {
    ...
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin( {
            __IMPORT_REGEX__: importRegex
        } )
    ]
}
```

```js
// App.js
const req = require.context('./components', true, __IMPORT_REGEX__)
```

One final note: Typescript users will need to declare a global for `__IMPORT_REGEX__`

```js
// interface.d.ts
declare global {
    var __IMPORT_REGEX__: RegExp
}
```