# Easier way to import scss in Angular 5

Tags: css, angular, typescript, sass

I've searched around but I cant seem to find an answer.. say I have a project and In my project I have a few `.scss` files like `mixins.scss`, `vars.scss` and `base.scss` now obviously I will want to use these files in my component `.scss` file.. is there a way I can import all of these one time and then use them throughout my project.. Its seem stupid that on every `.scss` file I have I need to write 6 import statements.. now Ive tried to add those files directly to the `angular-cli.json` file as well as importing them in my main `styles.scss` file but neither of those methods worked

Any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT**

Ive managed to find a work around by putting all my imports into a `main.scss` file but surely there has to be a better way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use webpack's [`require.context`](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#require-context) feature to require all of the files in a folder. [Here's an answer with a solution for that.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29421409/how-to-load-all-files-in-a-subdirectories-using-webpack-without-require-statemen#30652110)

```
requireAll(require.context('./styles/', true, /\.scss$/))
```